# extending django admin model

Tags: django, django-admin

The default view for a model on the django admin page shows a list of items in that view, but only gives one field. How is it possible to show multiple fields in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the function list_display() that does this job exactly:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Answer (score 1):

You can set list_display as like example;

```
@admin.register(Personal)
class PersonalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('id','name','surname','phone',)
```